# A suitable constructor for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TeamCloud.Areas.Identity.Data.TeamCloudUser]' could not be located

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on my ASP NET Core project with IdentityFramework and now I need to display list of users in parameters in table on my RazorPage. Also, I can't imagine how can I move object from razor OnGet method to view (I need to move members object and display it on view). Anyway, I need to display only users that has a similar Team that logged user has (see code below) but I stuck with this error. Hope u can help me. Thanks.

**Error**
[image]

**MembersList.cshtml**

```
@page
@using TeamCloud.Areas.Identity.Pages.Team.Manage
@model IEnumerable<TeamCloudUser>
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Список участников";
   ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.MembersList;
 }
 <br />
 <div style="text-align: center;">
     <h2 style="font-weight: 700;">Настройки команды</h2>
 </div>
 <hr />
 <partial name="_ManageNav" />
 <hr />

 <body class="index">
<form method="post" asp-page="MembersList">
    <h4 style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;">@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="AddMember" class="btn alert-primary" value="Добавить участника" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: 700;" />
        <br />
        <table class="table" style="text-align: center">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a>Имя</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a>Почта</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a>Кол-во файлов</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a>Объем памяти</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a>Действия</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var member in Model.TeamCloudUsers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.ProfileName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.Email)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.TotalFiles)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.TotalSize)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (@member.IsBlockedToUpload == true)
                        {
                            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOnAllow" class="">
                                <img style="width: 30px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/allow.png" title="Заблокировать" />
                            </a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOnBlock" class="">
                                <img style="width: 30px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/block.png" title="Заблокировать" />
                            </a>
                        }
                        <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOnDelete" class="">
                            <img style="width: 30px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/delete.png" title="Выгнать" />
                        </a>

                        <!--modalOnBlock-->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalOnBlock" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="title">Блокировка пользователя</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Запретить участнику "@member.Email" загружать новые файлы в командное хранилище?.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="BlockToUpload" class="btn alert-primary" value="@member.Id" name="userId">Запретить</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn alert-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--modalOnAllow-->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalOnAllow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="title">Разблокировка пользователя</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Предоставить пользователю "@member.Email" доступ к загрузке файлов в хранилище команды?
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="AllowToUpload" class="btn alert-primary" value="@member.Id" name="userId">Разрешить</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn alert-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--modalOnDelete-->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalOnDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="title">Исключение пользователя</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Исключить пользователя "@member.Email" из команды? (тут подумать над удалением его файлов)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="DeleteFromTeam" class="btn alert-primary" value="@member.Id" name="userId">Исключить</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn alert-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

**MembersList.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace TeamCloud.Areas.Identity.Pages.Team.Manage
{
 public class MembersListModel : PageModel
 {

    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
    private readonly UserManager<TeamCloudUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<TeamCloudUser> _logger;
    private readonly TeamCloudContext _context;

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-LRLFA5K\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TeamCloud;Integrated Security=True");

    private string currentUserId { get; set; }

    public MembersListModel(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, UserManager<TeamCloudUser> userManager, ILogger<TeamCloudUser> logger, TeamCloudContext context)
    {
        this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
    {
        var teamFounder = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
        currentUserId = teamFounder;
        int currentTeamId = FindTeamIdByName();
        var teamMembers = _context.AspNetUserTeams.Where(x => x.TeamId == currentTeamId).Select(x => x.UserId);
        string partialValue = null;
        var members = partialValue;
        foreach (var member in teamMembers)
        {
            members += _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == member).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return ??? //How to move object modal members to view in RazorPages?
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostAddMember()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("AddMember");
    }

    private int FindTeamIdByName()
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select TeamId from AspNetUserTeams where UserId = @userId", sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@userId"].Value = currentUserId;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = sqlCommand };
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        sqlConnection.Close();
        return Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TeamId"]);
    }
}
```

}

**TeamCloudUser**

```
namespace TeamCloud.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the TeamCloudUser class
    public class TeamCloudUser : IdentityUser
{
    //public virtual new string Email { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }

    public bool IsBlockedToUpload { get; set; }

    public int TotalFiles { get; set; }
    public string TotalSize { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need firstly learn how to get started in razor pages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages

Razor Pages do not use `@model ModelName`,it uses `@model <PageName>Model`,which is different from mvc.

For your requirement,you do not know how to return model in razor pages.Change like below:

MembersList.cshtml:

```
@page
@model MembersListModel    //change here
<body class="index">
    <form method="post" asp-page="MembersList">
        <h4 style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;">@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
        <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="AddMember" class="btn alert-primary" value="Добавить участника" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: 700;" />
            <br />
            <table class="table" style="text-align: center">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a>Имя</a>
                    </th>
                    //....
                </tr>
                @foreach (var member in Model.TeamCloudUsers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.ProfileName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.Email)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.TotalFiles)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.TotalSize)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (@member.IsBlockedToUpload == true)
                        {
                            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOnAllow" class="">
                                <img style="width: 30px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/allow.png" title="Заблокировать" />
                            </a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOnBlock" class="">
                                <img style="width: 30px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/block.png" title="Заблокировать" />
                            </a>
                        }
                        <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOnDelete" class="">
                            <img style="width: 30px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/delete.png" title="Выгнать" />
                        </a>

                        <!--modalOnBlock-->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalOnBlock" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="title">Блокировка пользователя</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Запретить участнику "@member.Email" загружать новые файлы в командное хранилище?.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="BlockToUpload" class="btn alert-primary" value="@member.Id" name="userId">Запретить</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn alert-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--modalOnAllow-->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalOnAllow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="title">Разблокировка пользователя</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Предоставить пользователю "@member.Email" доступ к загрузке файлов в хранилище команды?
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="AllowToUpload" class="btn alert-primary" value="@member.Id" name="userId">Разрешить</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn alert-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--modalOnDelete-->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalOnDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="title">Исключение пользователя</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Исключить пользователя "@member.Email" из команды? (тут подумать над удалением его файлов)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="DeleteFromTeam" class="btn alert-primary" value="@member.Id" name="userId">Исключить</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn alert-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

MembersList.cshtml.cs:

```
public class MembersListModel : PageModel
{
    //1. add the following property
    public IEnumerable<TeamCloudUser> TeamCloudUsers { get; set; }
    
    public void OnGet()
    {
        //2. set data for the property
        //for easy testing,I hard-coded the data
        //you could get the data from database
        //e.g. TeamCloudUsers = _context.AspNetUserTeams
        //                              .Where(x => x.TeamId == currentTeamId).ToList();
        TeamCloudUsers = new List<TeamCloudUser>()
        {
            new TeamCloudUser(){ ProfileName ="a",IsBlockedToUpload=false,Email="a@qq.com",TotalFiles=2,TotalSize="34"}
        };
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

Modify your code to:

```
                                         // change here...
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOnBlock_@member.Id" class="">
                                <img style="width: 30px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/block.png" title="Заблокировать" />
</a>
<!--modalOnBlock-->
                                 //change here...
<div class="modal fade" id="modalOnBlock_@member.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: So I got a new error: InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
on row                 TeamCloudUsers = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == member).ToList();

Comment: this is my OnGet method: public void OnGet()
        {
            var teamFounder = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            currentUserId = teamFounder;
            int currentTeamId = FindTeamIdByName();
            var teamMembers = _context.AspNetUserTeams.Where(x => x.TeamId == currentTeamId).Select(x => x.UserId);
            foreach (var member in teamMembers)
            {
                TeamCloudUsers = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == member).ToList();
            }          
        }

Comment: i think first datareader initialized in "var teamMembers =", but how can i close it and use new?

Comment: the first database query gets all userID that connected to current teamId, and the second query gets all users that I got in the first query by Id

Comment: OK.Firstly,please debug your code and check which line makes such error.Then What is your `AspNetUserTeams` table?Share a detailed model design and your TeamCloudContext will be helpful to reproduce your issue.You could edit your question and updated the code.Thanks.

Comment: AspNetUserTeams has two fields: UserId and TeamId. Its like a connector between Team and User. For teams i have AspNetTeams table. The idea is to display users' fileds on MembersList that currently connected to the team of logged in user.

Comment: So I need to get all users' Id's from AspNetUserTeams by TeamId and after that i need to get all users fields by Id's that i found in the previous query from the AspNetUserTeams

Comment: So what is your User and Team?Does User mean TeamCloudUser model?`Its like a connector between Team and User` So the AspNetUserTeams is the third table between User and Team,that is to say Team and User have many to many relationship,right?

Comment: No, user can has only one connector to team, but team can has many connectors to any user. 1 user = 1 team, but 1 team = many users. It works like AspNetRoleUsers but on some other rule

Comment: In the FindTeamByName() method i get teamId by logged in user and after that i user found teamId to get data on OnGet() method as u can see

Comment: TeamCloudUser is a model that has inheritance from IdentityUser. In the database it's AspNetUsers but with some additional fields like ProfileName, TotalSize and TotalFiles

Comment: I'm glad you resolve it.Just a note,I think you need to change the  `foreach (var member in teamMembers) { TeamCloudUsers = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == member).ToList(); }` to `TeamCloudUsers = _context.Users.Where(x => teamMembers.Contains(x.Id)).ToList(); ` .No need use `foreach`.I will always get the last record by using your foreach statement.

Comment: Rena, one more question, is it possible to move value from model to asp-page-handler method by clicking on button? this is my code from MembersList.cshtml 
<div class="modal-footer">
                                            <div>
                                                <button type="submit"  value="@member.Id" asp-page-handler="BlockUser" name="userId" class="btn alert-primary">Запретить</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

Comment: and this is my method onpost public IActionResult OnPostBlockUser(string userId)
        {
            Models.TeamConnector teamConnector = _context.AspNetUserTeams.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
            if (teamConnector != null)
            {
                _context.AspNetUserTeams.Remove(teamConnector);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Page();
        }

Comment: Of course you can.What you did could pass the userId to BlockUser handler.Did you have any problems?

Comment: Yes, I have some problems. This code (<button type="submit" asp-page-handler="BlockToUpload" class="btn alert-primary" value="@member.Id" name="userId">Запретить</button>) works well. but @member.Id is not an Id of selected user in table, it's Id of the first user in table... If i try to push the button on second row on the table that shows data from second user it doesn't gets an Id of user from this row where i pushed the button.

Comment: I edit MembersList.cshtml, you can see code

Comment: That is because although all of the modal contains different value but they all have the same modal id(`id="modalOnBlock"`),and your data-target is always `modalOnBlock`,so you will always open the first modal.